# Dynamic canvas re-sizing in KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

How can we achieve following in canvas created through KineticJS.

Canvas and its containing shapes should fit into stage accordingly as the browser window changes size.

I have tried following in jsfiddle,

```
   var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 100,
          y: 100,
          width: 100,
          height: 50,
          fill: 'red',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 10
      });

 var rect2 = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 150,
          y: 120,
          width: 100,
          height: 50,
          fill: 'green',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 10
      });
      layer.add(rect);
 layer.add(rect2);
      stage.add(layer);

      var onResize = function () {
          // browser viewport size
          var w = window.innerWidth;
          var h = window.innerHeight;

          // stage dimensions
          var ow = stage.getWidth(); // your stage width
          var oh = stage.getHeight(); // your stage height
          var keepAspectRatio = false;
          if (keepAspectRatio) {
              // keep aspect ratio
              var scale = Math.min(w / ow, h / oh);
              stage.setScale(scale);
              // adjust canvas size
              stage.setSize(ow * scale, oh * scale);

          } else {
              // scale to exact fit
              stage.setScale((w / ow), (h / oh));
              // adjust canvas size
              stage.setSize(stageWidth * getScaleX(), stageHeight * getScaleY());

          }

          // update the stage
          stage.draw()
      }



      window.onresize = function () {
          onResize();
      }
```

[resize jsfiddle reference](http://jsfiddle.net/gokuldahal/8k42u/)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `resize` event and resize the Kinetic `stage` with `setSize(width, height)` to achieve the desired result. To match the height use a variant of `window.innerHeight` property.

`window.onresize = function(){ ... }`

Comment: if the canvas has shapes in it, how can we make adjustments to those shapes as window resizes.

Comment: It seems rather than resize, scaling is what your are after. In that case, use `setScale(x,y)` method